# Serializing Pages in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Is there a way to serialize page data into an object array in Nuxt.js? I would like to create an index of all of my pages' data so I can create search functionality.

Comment: what do u mean by page data?

Comment: I would like to get the HTML and metadata from my pages in the Pages directory and convert them to a JSON object array. Is there a lifecycle hook during the "generate" action that would allow me to have access to that data?